# Comparing 2 columns for certain words

Tags: google-sheets

=COUNTIF(B4:B, "*" & D4:D & "*")

So column B4:B will have something like this
Joe Smith, STIM
and column D4:D would have something like this
Joe Smith 10/19/1999 AC

I am trying to make a True False statment in Col G that if column B has Joe Smith and Column D has Joe smith it will say yes or no. This will be a list of names that always change dynamically so one day B4 might be Joe Smith but the next day it could be Jan Doe. Column D will be a list of names in alpha order that changes all the time as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate what you need with the example provided by using:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(D:D="",,REGEXMATCH(LOWER(D:D),FILTER(LOWER(I:I),I:I<>"")&"\b")))
```

You can see the results in my testing spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I7YbwzWPRl5dNLONPFOqaC7MA2oQXrrcS5-mOAd0XV0/edit?usp=sharing).

At the moment I have limited the range from column I but you can just change it so it takes the whole column.

Just one little detail is that with this function you can only have 1 name in each row in the list of names.

Comment: Added a picture in description

Comment: @JeremiahHall I think I may have misunderstood the initial question. Are you trying to compare if the names from column B match any of the rows from column D, or just to compare the value next to them? For example B4 with D4, and B5 with D5 or B4 with the whole D column, then B5 with the whole column and so on?

Comment: Yes. I want to compare if the names from B match D. But just the names not all the varibles.

Comment: @JeremiahHall I have updated the answer. Let me know if that is useful.